# Android app rejected by Google Play Console due to "Provide instructions for app access"

Tags: android, firebase, google-play, google-play-console

I'm developing an app that integrates Firebase Authentication for its login system. I'm using "Login with Google" for my main login and registration systems. When submitting the app to the Google Play Console, My app got rejected twice and the message was "Action Required: Provide instructions for app access".

Below is the message that I get in my email.

I have provided a Google account for this. And google still rejected my app? Do you guys have any idea what should I do?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure to have filled right fields where to put Username and Password for Google tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to go in google console to content application , application access and then provide a gmail account and pass for them to try to access.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new google account for demo purposes and remove 2 step verification if any

provide your email and password

also, check your app signing key in the firebase console that match with play console key

[image]

[image]